# Can't save certificate into local disk using python

Tags: python, sockets, x509certificate

I am trying to load remote server certificate and save it in my local disk. This is the python script I'm using:

```
from M2Crypto.X509 import FORMAT_PEM

import StringIO
import traceback
from M2Crypto.Err import SSLError
import ssl
import socket
import pprint
import M2Crypto
from M2Crypto import X509, RSA
from datetime import datetime

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)  
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
port = 443
host='216.58.212.67' #google

#creating ssl socket
ssock = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET), server_hostname=host)

#ssl connection
try:
    ssock.connect((host, port))
except socket.error: #if tls connection is not possible
    print "Faile connection with: " + host

#get the certificate
cert = ssock.getpeercert(True)
x509 = M2Crypto.X509.load_cert_der_string(cert)
x509_file= M2Crypto.X509.load_cert('C:/Users/xxx/Documents/temp',format=FORMAT_PEM)
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ealas/PycharmProjects/tlsScan/test.py", line 36, in <module>
    x509_file= M2Crypto.X509.load_cert('C:/Users/xxx/Documents/temp',format=FORMAT_PEM)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\M2Crypto\X509.py", line 609, in load_cert
    bio = BIO.openfile(file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\M2Crypto\BIO.py", line 186, in openfile
    return File(open(filename, mode))
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/xxx/Documents/temp'
```

What is wrong in my code please?

Comment: Well, what are the permissions for that file? It doesn't seem like there's any problem with your code.

Comment: It is a folder. The script should write the certificate on it.

Comment: That's the problem. You can't write data to a folder, you have to specify a file in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying a folder when you should be specifying a file. According to the [documentation for the M2Crypto.X509.load_cert function](http://nullege.com/codes/search/M2Crypto.X509.load_cert), you should be specifying the path to a file, not a folder:

> Load certificate from file.
>
> @type file: string
>   @param file: Name of file containing certificate in either DER or PEM format.

If you try and load data from or write data to a folder instead of a file, you will get a "Permission denied" error, at least on Windows. To test this, I created a folder called `temp`, and tried to read data from it and write data to it, and I got the exact same error as in your question:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    with open(r'C:\Users\Random\Documents\temp', 'w') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Random\\Documents\\temp'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    with open(r'C:\Users\Random\Documents\temp', 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Random\\Documents\\temp'
```

In the future, you should look at the documentation for the functions you're using to ensure that you're passing not only the right type of variable to it, but also that the data itself is what the function expects.

Also, in your question you said you're trying to write to a file, but you're using a function which reads from a file. I would suggest going through and making sure you're doing what you think you're doing. Again, reading the documentation for the library you're using will be helpful.